# Minimum Priority Queue implementation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, priority-queue

Below you can find a generic implementation and some unit tests of a minimum priority queue in Kotlin.

What could be improved in this implementation, so that it complies to best coding practices in Kotlin?

```
import java.util.*

class MinHeapPQ<Key> : Iterable<Key> {

    private var pq: Array<Key?>

    private var n = 0

    private var comparator: Comparator<Key>? = null

    constructor(initCapacity: Int) : this(initCapacity, null)

    constructor() : this(1)

    constructor(comparator: Comparator<Key>?) : this(1, comparator)

    constructor(initCapacity: Int, comparator: Comparator<Key>?) {
        this.comparator = comparator
        pq = arrayOfNulls<Any?>(initCapacity + 1) as Array<Key?>
    }

    constructor(keys: Array<Key>) : this(keys.size) {
        n = keys.size
        for (i in 0..n - 1) {
            pq[i + 1] = keys[i]
        }
        for (k in n / 2 downTo 1) {
            sink(k)
        }
        assert(isMinHeap())
    }

    fun isEmpty() = n == 0

    fun size() = n

    fun min(): Key {
        require(!isEmpty()) { "Priority queue underflow" }
        return pq[1]!!
    }

    fun insert(x: Key): MinHeapPQ<Key> {
        if (n == pq.size - 1) {
            resize(2 * pq.size)
        }
        pq[++n] = x
        swim(n)
        assert(isMinHeap())
        return this
    }

    fun delMin(): Key {
        require(!isEmpty()) { "Cannot retrieve minimum record. Priority queue is empty" }
        val min = pq[1]
        exch(1, n--)
        sink(1)
        pq[n + 1] = null
        assert(isMinHeap())
        return if (min != null) min else throw NullPointerException("'min' must not be null")
    }

    override fun iterator(): Iterator<Key> {
        return HeapIterator(comparator, size(), n, pq)
    }

    private fun swim(k: Int) {
        var myK = k
        while (myK > 1 && greater(myK / 2, myK)) {
            exch(myK, myK / 2)
            myK /= 2
        }
    }

    private fun sink(k: Int) {
        var myK = k
        while (2 * myK <= n) {
            var j = 2 * myK
            if (j < n && greater(j, j + 1)) j++
            if (!greater(myK, j)) return
            exch(myK, j)
            myK = j
        }
    }

    private fun greater(i: Int, j: Int): Boolean {
        return if (comparator == null) (pq[i] as Comparable<Key>) > pq[j]!!
        else comparator!!.compare(pq[i], pq[j]) > 0
    }

    private fun exch(i: Int, j: Int) {
        pq[i] = pq[j].also { pq[j] = pq[i] }
    }

    private fun isMinHeap(): Boolean = isMinHeap(1)

    private fun isMinHeap(k: Int): Boolean {
        if (k > n) return true
        val left = 2 * k
        val right = 2 * k + 1
        when {
            left <= n && greater(k, left) -> return false
            right <= n && greater(k, right) -> return false
            else -> {
                return isMinHeap(left) && isMinHeap(right)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun resize(capacity: Int) {
        assert(capacity > n)
        val temp = arrayOfNulls<Any>(capacity) as Array<Key?>
        for (i in 1..n) {
            temp[i] = pq[i]
        }
        pq = temp
    }

    class HeapIterator<out Key>(comparator: Comparator<Key>?, size: Int, n: Int, pq: Array<Key?>) : Iterator<Key> {

        private val copy: MinHeapPQ<Key> = if (comparator == null) MinHeapPQ<Key>(size) else MinHeapPQ<Key>(size, comparator)

        override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
            return !copy.isEmpty()
        }

        override fun next(): Key {
            require(hasNext()) {"Queue is empty"}
            return copy.delMin()
        }

        init {
            for (i in 1..n)
                copy.insert(pq[i]!!)
        }

    }

}
```

Here are some JUnit 4 tests:

```
import org.hamcrest.core.Is.`is`
import org.junit.Assert.assertThat
import org.junit.Test

class MinHeapPQTest {

    @Test
    fun delMin() {
        val pq = MinHeapPQ<Int>()
        pq.insert(5).insert(9).insert(3)
        assertThat(pq.min(), `is`(3))
        pq.insert(10)
        assertThat(pq.delMin(), `is`(3))
        assertThat(pq.size(), `is`(3))
        assertThat(pq.delMin(), `is`(5))
        assertThat(pq.delMin(), `is`(9))
        assertThat(pq.delMin(), `is`(10))
        assertThat(pq.isEmpty(), `is`(true))
        assertThat(pq.size(), `is`(0))
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException::class)
    fun delMin_underflow() {
        val pq = MinHeapPQ<Int>()
        pq.min()
    }

    @Test
    fun iterator() {
        val pq = MinHeapPQ<Int>(arrayOf(10, 8, 3, 9, 7, 5, 6, 2, 1, 4))
        val sorted = pq.iterator().asSequence().toList()
        for (i in 1..10) {
            assertThat(sorted[i - 1], `is`(i))
        }
    }

}
```

This implementation is a port of Robert Sedgewick's and Kevin Wayne's MinPQ implementation. See http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq

Answer (score 4):

## Until

```
for (i in 0..n - 1) {
```

can be replaced with

```
for (i in (0 until n))
```

## Lift return from when

```
when {
    left <= n && greater(k, left) -> return false
    right <= n && greater(k, right) -> return false
    else -> {
        return isMinHeap(left) && isMinHeap(right)
    }
}
```

can be replaced with

```
return when {
    left <= n && greater(k, left) -> false
    right <= n && greater(k, right) -> false
    else -> isMinHeap(left) && isMinHeap(right)
}
```